# iOS/Android Syncing with Delphi/C# Desktop Application

Tags: android, .net, ios, delphi, sqlite

Not sure if this is the correct Stack Exchange website but here goes..

A client has asked me to look into the possibility of having a iOS or Android App for typing in information storing that in a SQLLite database and then syncing up with the main desktop application when plugged in by cable or something other syncing technology.

The desktop application is a Windows one written currently in Delphi 7.

Are there any API's to sync data from a SQLLite database on iOS/Android that Delphi can use?

If not, then would it be better if the desktop application was written in C# as its a newer language that can consume the API's easier?

Comment: If you're voting to close. Please tell me why or suggest a better place to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unidirectional sync (device to desktop), I would start with a simple web service (HTTP based). The new Web Sockets standard, also based on HTTP, is a little more complicated, but would allow for bidirectional communication.

The devices can HTTP POST database changes to the server, and the desktop client can pull new data (using HTTP GET) or receive push notifications, for example using a Web Sockets client.

For desktop to device you could also check out Apple Push Notifications and the corresponding Android technology.

For high availability I recommend a cloud-based solution like Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2), Google App Engine (GAE) or Azure.

Comment: Thanks. Really surpised that there isnt a different way of doing it other than HTTP POST. Thought there might be a framework like desktop sync but more improved these days

Comment: See my edit, Web Sockets are also possible between a central server and the devices, and allow bidirectional sync.

Comment: I don't want bidirectional sync thanks. Simply device to desktop.

Comment: `syncing up with the main desktop application when plugged in by cable` - in this case, the easiest way would be to copy the database file ;)

Comment: Can you do this with iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather broad, there are many things you could do here.  There aare so many technologies to use it's blinding.

The prevailing technique for transferring information from mobile devices is REST (over http).

You could also whip something up rather swiftly in node.js or WFC to create a service to collect information from the mobile devices.

I'm not sure about Delphi libraries available but perhaps by including REST in your search term you may have more luck.  You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959851/using-rest-with-delphi for a start.

The mobile side may be more tricky.  If you are developing for multiple devices you may wish to explore the cross platform developer framework by [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) as there seems to be a few projects that aim to sync local databases to the cloud.  How you tie these together will be an interesting task.

Good luck!!!